# How to configure the SSL certificate in JBOSS EAP 7.3

Tags: ssl, jboss, keystore, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am still new to JBOSS EAP  and I have trouble configuring the server to use my let's encrypt certificate. I have tried to import the certificate into a pkcs12 file and then to a Keystore in my `EAP/standalone/configuration` folder. Moreover, I followed the steps found in this documentation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/index. However the configuration does not see me be working and ie inside the server shows me the error attached to the screenshot.[ie error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/577nw.png). Any help will be greatly appreciated.